# Glassfish : increase start-domain timeout

Tags: java, glassfish

I'm trying to start a domain in glassfish 3.1.1. During this start, a database migration is performed, which is very long in my case, and glassfish falls in a timeout :

```
> asadmin start-domain MyDomain
```

[the domain tries to start]

```
No response from the Domain Administration Server (MyDomain) after 600 seconds.
The command is either taking too long to complete or the server has failed.
Please see the server log files for command status.  
Please start with the --verbose option in order to see early messages.
Command start-domain failed.
```

My question is : How can I increase the time out for the command start-domain ? 600 seconds is not enough.

Comment: you could disable the application start the domain and re-enable the application.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately it looks like that is not an option at this point.

If you look in to:

`\glassfishv3\glassfish\modules\admin-cli.jar` you will find `StartDomainCommand.class` in there, you will see:

```
  private boolean timedOut(long startTime) {
    return System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime > 600000L;
  }
```

Note, that 600 seconds (or 600000 mills) is hard coded.

It looks like this has been registered as a bug. See [here](https://java.net/jira/browse/GLASSFISH-19371).

Sorry to be the bearer of bad news, I'd like to see this resolved too.

Answer (score 0):

Since Eclipse GlassFish 7.0.0 you can reset some defaults. Try to set the environment property before you use the `asadmin` command. The value is in millis, so this sets the timeout to 10 minutes:

`export AS_START_TIMEOUT=600000`

These are configurable values:

- `AS_START_TIMEOUT` to override default timeout 60 s for the start domain command.
- `AS_STOP_TIMEOUT` to override default timeout 60 s for the stop domain command.